# svnadmin create: Option Expected

Tags: svn, ubuntu-9.10, svnadmin

Can someone enlighten me on this...

When I uncomment the line in /etc/subversion/config `store-auth-creds = no`, and when I create a new repo, I see the following error:

```
svnadmin: /etc/subversion/config:37: Option Expected
```

I understand that that 37 line is pointing to the `store-auth-creds = no` option but what option does svnadmin expect now??

Kind of new in SVN.. =) and I'm using Ubuntu 9.1 for my SVN.

Comment: jus to add on, "store-auth-creds = no" is an option for the system NOT to store any credentials previously entered.

 =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either your **svnadmin** does not recognize store-auth-creds or you have messed up the config file as you edited it (a space character where it doesn't belong etc).

Answer (score 7):

Try to remove the white spaces before the options enabled.

For example in svnserve.conf we enable following options :

```
anon-access=read
auth-access=write
password-db=passwd
```

Make sure there is not even single space before these options.
I was facing same issue and it resolved when I checked it for extra spaces in such conf file.

In your case there must be space before

```
store-auth-creds=no
```

remove those extra spaces and problem will be resolved.

Comment: Oh! subvesion! ... so funny

Answer (score 2):

ran into a similar problem. Was getting the following error "svn E200002: error while parsing config file"

White spaces was the cause. removing resolved

```
store-passwords = yes
store-ssl-client-cert-pp = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = yes
store-ssl-client-cert-pp-plaintext = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: Also make sure to remove any leading spaces from the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, trying to set up subversion for my Xcode project.

> svnadmin: /Users/admin/.subversion/config:94: Option expected

For some reason, subversion's config file has split line 94,
chopping up comments that are started by `###` into 2 separate lines. Edit the config file to restore the comment to 1 line, or add `###` to the front of the 2nd line. Voila, problem solved.

Comment: By the way, I needed to add one hashtag `#` to line 116 also.